# Chrome doesn't offer to save password of my ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, passwords

I'm developing a website using ASP.NET.

I have a form with user name / password and a connect button.

Internet Explorer and Firefox prompt me to save the password, but Google Chrome doesn't.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your Chrome browser settings:

settings -> advanced -> Offer to save passwords I enter on the web

Answer (score 0):

It can be because the form is not actually being "submitted". Check the onsubmit attribute to see if it returns false, which cancels the submission.

Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119385/why-doesnt-chrome-recognize-this-login-form

The important comment is:

> Yes, it doesn't work when you remove
>   return false. You will need to rewrite
>   your code. Chrome does not offer to
>   save passwords from forms that are not
>   "submitted" as a security feature. If
>   you want the Save Password feature to
>   work, you're going to have to ditch
>   the whole fancy AJAX login.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your site has a SSL/TLS certificate that Chrome thinks is “iffy”.  See:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=431618